# Why I have this error? ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm creating a android application. When I tested in Emulator, Samsung S8 Plus and General Mobile GM8, I haven't any error but play console always gives me some crushes.

Code is:

```
int count = getItemCount() >= 30 ? 30 : getItemCount();
if (count == 0)
    return new long[] {0};

long[] result = new long[count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    result[i] = users.get(i).getPk();
return result;
```

Error message:
**ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

How I can fix it I really do not know.

Comment: for eg. if count is 4 and users list have only 3 data or less than count then it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

Comment: maybe your users variable don't have any element

Comment: @Nirav Bhavsar What can I do then in this code?

Comment: @Burcu Tarbil, please refer my below answer

Comment: Calling `getItemCount()` twice is dangerous (cuz value might vary depending on timing), you need to put it in a variable instead. I am guessing your error is a result of race condition (though not enough code to prove it).

Comment: I would suggest that you include the whole adapter code. Q: Are you using another thread for updating your adapter by chance?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Answer (score 1):

remove the "=" sign in the condition it will work properly :

```
int count = getItemCount() > 30 ? 30 : getItemCount();
        if (count == 0)
            return new long[] {0};

        long[] result = new long[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            result[i] = users.get(i).getPk();
        return result;
```

Comment: How does this resolve OP's problem if the users list has fewer than 30 items?

Comment: can you give a full code with method getItemCount() and which line gives the error

Answer (score 0):

For eg. if count is 4 and users list have only 3 data or less than count then it will throw `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

To avoid `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` try below approach

```
int count = getItemCount() >= 30 ? 30 : getItemCount();
    if (count == 0)
        return new long[] {0};

    long[] result = new long[count];
    if(users != null && users.size() > 0){
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++){
            if(i >= users.size()){
                break;
            }
            result[i] = users.get(i).getPk();
        }
    }

return result;
```

Comment: I think it's will work. I'll update my app again and I'll look it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @BurcuTarbil, Welcome mate:)

Comment: This couldn't work still I have this error. Sorry mate.

Comment: @BurcuTarbil, at which line you are still getting error

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is an array with size equal to the size of the `users` list with maximum 30 items and minimum 1 element, then change `count` to the `users` list size if this size is less than 30:

```
    int count = getItemCount() >= 30 ? 30 : getItemCount();
    if (count > users.size())
        count = users.size();
    if (count == 0)
        return new long[] {0};

    long[] result = new long[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        result[i] = users.get(i).getPk();
    return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

It can happen because of out of index.
Let me make it simple if array have 4 indexes so

```
a=[0,1,2,3]//eg:
```

SO that if you want to print a[0] then 
o/p=

```
0
```

But for a[5]:
you will have **ArrayOutofBoundsExeption**

Here in your example you have not specified your user field How it is generated so after making some assumptions..
Im telling you

```
result[i] = users.get(i).getPk();
```

here the problem is occured in users.get(i)
where user field is not that contains value but it may be dynamic:
so my solution will be
You should use
Try exception and just pass it  **ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**

and raise exception your program should work fine!
I hope it will help you!

Comment: **It is bad idea to catch an unchecked exception like ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException**, you should fix the code by finding the root issue rather than hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems the size of `users` list does not equal to `counts` and it is smaller. so to prevent `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, I suggest to edit your code in this way:

```
int count = getItemCount() >= 30 ? 30 : getItemCount();
count = count > users.size()  ? users.size() : count;
        if (count == 0)
            return new long[] {0};

        long[] result = new long[count];
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            result[i] = users.get(i).getPk();
        return result;
```

by modifying your code like that, in situations that `users` list is greater than `counts`, you will not have any controls on the items at the end of `users` list.